# Credit usage of repetitive warehouse suspension & resumption in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm curious about the usage/credits/cost implications of resuming & suspending a warehouse multiple times within one minute (whether this happens manually or automatically).

The Snowflake documentation is slightly ambiguous regarding this edge case.

From [Virtual Warehouse Credit Usage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#virtual-warehouse-credit-usage):

> The credit numbers shown here are for a full hour of usage; however, credits are billed per-second, with a 60-second (i.e. 1-minute) minimum:
>
> - Each time a warehouse is started or resized to a larger size, the warehouse is billed for 1 minute’s worth of usage based on the hourly rate shown above.
> - Stopping and restarting a warehouse within the first minute does not change the amount billed; the minimum billing charge is 1 minute.

From [How are Credits Charged for Warehouses?](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#how-are-credits-charged-for-warehouses):

> When warehouses are provisioned:
>
> - The minimum billing charge for provisioning a warehouse is 1 minute (i.e. 60 seconds).
> - There is no benefit to stopping a warehouse before the first 60-second period is over because the credits have already been billed for that period.
> - After the first 60 seconds, all subsequent billing for a running warehouse (until it is shut down). Three examples are provided below:
>
>   - If a warehouse runs for 30 to 60 seconds, it is billed for 60 seconds.
>   - If a warehouse runs for 61 seconds, it is billed for only 61 seconds.
>   - If a warehouse runs for 61 seconds, shuts down, and then restarts and runs for less than 60 seconds, it is billed for 121 seconds (60 + 1 + 60).

What I'm looking for would be an example along the lines of:

- If a warehouse runs for 10 seconds, shuts down, and then immediately restarts and runs for another 10 seconds:

  - is it billed for 60 seconds?
  - or is it billed for 120 seconds (60 + 60)?

I assume it is the latter, but I would like to know for sure.

Comment: I assume the latter. Because "it might not be the same hardware", then again "it might be the same hardware". But I would be inclined to suggest to not rely on it. But I would also suggest testing the concept. So will no do so.

Comment: You're right! I just ran a test, and resuming the warehouse in quick succession incurred a charge of 60 seconds each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create warehouse timetest2 WAREHOUSE_SIZE = XSMALL INITIALLY_SUSPENDED = TRUE;
use warehouse timetest2;

alter warehouse timetest2 RESUME;

select sum(random()) 
from table(generator(TIMELIMIT => 10));

alter warehouse timetest2 SUSPEND;
```

with the last three steps done twice, with 5 seconds of pause.

```
select start_time, 
    warehouse_name, 
    credits_used_compute, 
    round(credits_used_compute * 60,3) as minutes_billed
from table(information_schema.warehouse_metering_history(dateadd('hour',-1,current_timestamp)));
```

| START_TIME | WAREHOUSE_NAME | CREDITS_USED_COMPUTE | MINUTES_BILLED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-16 15:32:36.000 -0700 | TIMETEST2 | 0.033333333 | 2 |
| 2022-04-16 15:32:36.000 -0700 | TIMETEST | 0.033333333 | 2 |

Done twice, just incase as the first was sloppy. It seems to bill per minute as noted.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran some tests, and the results are clear:

**Each restart of a warehouse (no matter the context or when it was last suspended), will incur the 60 seconds minimum charge.**

I tested with a Medium warehouse (4/60 credits per minute):

- Resuming 6 times, minutes apart: 0.40 credits
- Resuming 6 times within the same minute: 0.40 credits