# How to monitor & optimize warehouse usage for very short workloads in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The use case is for very short workloads with an unpredictable schedule (the workloads may or may not overlap):

- Is it better to suspend the warehouse immediately at the end of each workload (assuming no other workload is running), and [incur another 60 seconds of credits if it gets resumed immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898098/credit-usage-of-repetitive-warehouse-suspension-resumption-in-snowflake)?
- Or would it be better to leave the warehouse running/idle for some amount of time? This would be in the hope of avoiding the unnecessary warehouse resume charge of 60 seconds, but would also come with the possibility of costing more due to the increased idle time at the end of workloads (before the warehouse gets suspended).

What would be the best way to monitor & optimize warehouse usage for this use case?

All the options I can find are hourly, which doesn't provide the level of detail necessary:

- [WAREHOUSE_LOAD_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/warehouse_load_history.html) & [WAREHOUSE_LOAD_HISTORY View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_load_history.html)
- [WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/warehouse_metering_history.html) & [WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_metering_history.html)

And monitoring at the query level doesn't always exactly correspond to warehouse usage/runtime.

Comment: WAREHOUSE_LOAD_HISTORY is in 5mns band, which makes it quite useful actually

Answer (score 2):

Ah, just discovered a new `account_usage` view which might do the trick:

[WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_events_history.html) (currently in public preview)

It has all the information/events about warehouses resuming & suspending, so it should allow to build a good understanding of the costs involved with each resume/suspend cycle!

***Edit:*** Using this view, I've come up with a query to display each resume/suspend cycle (just need to specify a `warehouse_name` and a `timestamp`/date range):

```sql
WITH events AS (
  SELECT
    event_name,
    timestamp,
    LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS previous_timestamp,
    TIMEDIFF(second, previous_timestamp, timestamp) AS duration
  FROM snowflake.account_usage.warehouse_events_history
  WHERE warehouse_name = 'my_warehouse'
    AND timestamp > DATEADD(day, -7, CURRENT_DATE())
    AND event_name IN ('RESUME_WAREHOUSE', 'SUSPEND_WAREHOUSE')
    AND event_state = 'COMPLETED'
),
cycles AS (
  SELECT
    previous_timestamp AS resumed,
    timestamp AS suspended,
    duration,
    LAG(suspended) OVER (ORDER BY suspended) AS previous_suspension,
    TIMEDIFF(second, previous_suspension, resumed) AS suspended_duration
  FROM events
  WHERE event_name = 'SUSPEND_WAREHOUSE'
  ORDER BY resumed
)
SELECT
  resumed,
  suspended,
  duration,
  suspended_duration
FROM cycles;
```

It produces the following results (durations are in seconds):

| RESUMED | SUSPENDED | DURATION | SUSPENDED_DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-16 00:04:28.375 | 2022-04-16 00:05:05.652 | 37 | NULL |
| 2022-04-16 00:05:28.478 | 2022-04-16 00:06:03.504 | 35 | 23 |
| 2022-04-16 00:10:14.254 | 2022-04-16 00:11:17.706 | 63 | 251 |
| 2022-04-16 00:12:24.559 | 2022-04-16 00:14:12.630 | 108 | 67 |

From these results, we can tell that the first two cycles could have benefited from being combined (but not by that much):

- Separate: 120 seconds of usage

  - 37 second cycle = charged for 60 seconds
  - 35 second cycle = charged for 60 seconds
- Combined: over 95 seconds of usage

  - 37 seconds of usage + 23 seconds idle + 35 seconds of usage + some idle time before suspending

Whereas the other two cycles would not benefit at all -- more idle time would only increase the total usage/costs (over 60 seconds).

So in the end, it's probably not worth the trouble trying to optimize these cycles at all (unless they're very predictable) -- eager suspension of warehouses seems to remain the most economical approach (even with the occasional extra charge for the 60 seconds minimum).

A more impactful approach would probably be to try and improve the synchronization of the workloads instead (so that they run together/in parallel/at the same time, and share the same warehouse usage/cycle).

But of course, YMMV.

Comment: And one might want to consider the query delay implied by the warehouse resume... Although this might not matter depending on the usage type